# Does Google Chrome have a flag to disable anti-aliasing on WebGL?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, switch, anti-aliasing, webgl

I have an issue I would like to investigate but I don't know how to disable anti-aliasing.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled on a site by site basis. If you are testing your site. This is a link to an overview of the code that needs to be changed in processing.js.

http://asalga.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/webgl-anti-aliasing-in-processingjs/
If you need to test on another persons site you could try downloading the source for their site then testing it that way.

A good easy way to copy a website is to use httrack.
www.httrack.com
It's a website copier that also has a firefox extension called spiderzilla.